# Prevent output of carriage return with readline

Tags: c, linux, readline

I'm new to the Gnu Readline library.

I need to call the `readline()` function when the cursor is at the very last line of the console. But I need to prevent scrolling down when the <kbd>Return</kbd> key is pressed; so I'm looking for a way to prevent the output of the carriage return : I'm sure it's possible, but can't find the way to do it.

I tried to use my own `rl_getc_function()` to trap the <kbd>Return</kbd> key (the example below traps <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>z</kbd> keys, but it's just for test purposes) and treat this key in a special way:

- My first idea was to run the `accept-line` command directly, thinking it would not output a carriage return, but actually, it does
- My second idea was to redirect the output to `/dev/null` before calling the `accept-line` command; but the redirection doesn't seem to apply when the `readline()` function is already running.

Here is an example of my tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

FILE *devnull; // To test output redirecting

int my_getc(FILE *file)
{
    int c = getc(file);

    // Let's test something when the 'y' key is pressed:
    if (c == 'y') {
        // I was thinking that calling "accept-line" directly
        // would prevent the output of a carriage return:
        rl_command_func_t *accept_func = rl_named_function("accept-line");
        accept_func(1, 0);
        return 0;
    }

    // Another test, when 'z' key is pressed:
    if (c == 'z') {
        // Try a redirection:
        rl_outstream = devnull;
        // As the redirection didn't work unless I set it before
        // the readline() call, I tried to add this call,
        // but it doesn't initialize the output stream:
        rl_initialize();
        return 'z';

    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    devnull = fopen("/dev/null", "w");

    // Using my function to handle key input:
    rl_getc_function = my_getc;

    // Redirection works if I uncomment the following line:
    // rl_outstream = devnull;

    readline("> "); // No freeing for this simplified example
    printf("How is it possible to remove the carriage return before this line?\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure I missed the right way to do it; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it : the `rl_done` variable is made for this.

If I add this code to my `my_getc()` function, it works well:

```
if (c == '\r') {
    rl_done = 1;
    return 0;

}
```

No carriage return is then inserted, and my next `printf()` call displays just after the last char I typed.