# How can I read user input using Term::ReadLine without having the newline character printed out?

Tags: perl, readline

How can I read user input using `Term::ReadLine` without having a newline character printed out when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

The reason why I want to do this is because I want to read user input from a prompt at the very bottom of the screen (as in `less` or `vim`). Currently, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> causes the screen to scroll down, and that can be an issue. Also, I'd like to avoid having to appeal to `ncurses` at this point.

Setting
`$term->Attribs->{echo_control_characters}` to `0`, `undef`, or `off` doesn't seem to work.

```
#!perl
use Term::ReadLine;
use Term::ReadKey;
my $term = new Term::ReadLine ('me');
$term->ornaments(0);
$term->Attribs->{echo_control_characters} = 0;
print STDERR "\e[2J\e[s\e[" . ( ( GetTerminalSize() ) [1] )  . ";1H";  # clear screen, save cursor position, and go to the bottom;
my $input = $term->readline('> ');
print STDOUT "\e[uinput = $input\n";   # restore cursor position, and print
```

I could do that using `Term::ReadKey` with `cbreak` as read mode:

```
#!perl
use Term::ReadKey;
ReadMode 'cbreak';
my ( $k, $input );
print STDERR "> ";
while ( defined ( $k = ReadKey 0 ) and $k !~ /\n/ )
{
  $input .= $k;
  print STDERR $k;
}
print STDOUT "input = $input\n";
ReadMode 'restore';
```

But then I wouldn't be able to use `Term::ReadLine` features, such as history, completion, and line editing.

Comment: Which version of `ReadLine` are you using? E.g. `Term::ReadLine::Perl`, `Term::ReadLine::Perl5`, or `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`.. If you don't know, you can print it out using `say $term->ReadLine()`

Comment: It's the default one: `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`.

Comment: See also [Prevent output of carriage return with readline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34104757/2173773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `rl_getc_function` to intercept the carriage return before it is printed as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34104757/2173773) question. The following works for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    $ENV{PERL_RL} = "Gnu";
}
use Term::ReadLine;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('me');
my $attr = $term->Attribs;
$term->ornaments(0);
$attr->{getc_function} = sub {
    my $ord = $term->getc($attr->{instream});
    if ( $ord == 13 ) {  # carriage return pressed
        $attr->{done} = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    return $ord;
};
print STDERR "\e[2J\e[s\e[" . ( ( GetTerminalSize() ) [1] )  . ";1H";
my $input = $term->readline('> ');
print STDOUT "\e[uinput = $input\n";   # restore cursor position, and print
```